# Matlab : How to align title to the top center of a plot inside figure when saving as pdf?

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using `print(figName, '-dpdf');` to save matlab figures to pdf file. However the titles are not aligned corretly. I found the title is at the center of the whole figure, not the plot box(i.e. moved left because y-labels.)
Anyway to correct this issue?

Comment: I always suggest `export_fig` as an alternative to `print`

Comment: @AnderBiguri By quick test, I found `export_fig` is magic! Perfectly keeps what I see.